# Is there a way to getting Remix to run offline?

Tags: solidity, remix, solc, ide, offline

Could you please help me getting Remix IDE run in an offline environment?
I've researched that way from google but found no answers for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it. Check out [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project#offline-usage).

Answer (score 0):

[**Remix Desktop IDE**](https://remix-project.org/) allows to run Remix ***offline***. Here is the [releases](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases) page.

You can connect it to a wide range of VMs, testnets, RPCs, even some L2 !

[image]

I find it very useful because it has access to my **computer's file system**. No need to connect *buggy Remix-D* anymore, and you can use it even offline without a connection !

I still wonder why not so many people use the Desktop version !